# SSL for sharepoint wildcard with SANS

Tags: app, ssl

our security guy told me that he will only buy 1 wildcard SSL and it should work with apps as well. here is the break down. What do you guys think?

```
CN - *.myNOV.com

SAN names:
----------------
*.myNOV.com
MyNOV.com
*.apps.myNOV.com
Apps.myNOV.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that will work -- you can use a single SAN cert with wildcard entries.

Comment: Thank you @Trevor-Seward . your awesome.